# Receiving Bulk Insert Error 1450 (error not found) when executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

Cannot bulk load because the file "\\servername\sharedfolder\folder\file.txt" could not be opened. Operating System error code 1450 (error not found)

The file.txt is on a shared folder in a remote network. I have already googled and tried to apply almost every single entry on the web related to this issue but still unresolved.

I tried windows authentication,sql server authentication, made sure that I have bulkadmin role, requested full access to shared folder from dba.

The error 1450( error not found) is so vague.

Comment: should be \\servername\sharedfolder\folder\file.txt   .. double backslashes

Comment: edited to add another backslash

Comment: Sql Server authentication works fine now but not for Windows Authentication

Comment: In SSMS can you login as windows user?

Comment: Yes I can login.

Comment: Can you make sure your sqlservice accnt has access to your network drive?